# Ubuntu partitioning setup for running docker machines on windows box

Tags: windows, docker, virtualbox, ubuntu-14.04

I am trying to setup Ubuntu trusty version on my Windows box using Oracle VM for running docket containers. I did install Ubuntu and selected "erase and install new OS+logical partitioning as options while installing. Now, when i try to run docker get the below warning: WARN[0000] Your kernel does not support swap memory limit.

Did some research and seems like this is the answer: https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/ubuntulinux/ but warns of 10% performance loss (cgroup mounting) and this https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/16298.

```
 
    Current partitions:
    Filesystem                   Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
    /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root   25G  4.1G   20G  18% /
    none                         4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
    udev                         3.3G  4.0K  3.3G   1% /dev
    tmpfs                        672M  956K  671M   1% /run
    none                         5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
    none                         3.3G  152K  3.3G   1% /run/shm
    none                         100M   52K  100M   1% /run/user
    /dev/sda1                    236M   38M  186M  17% /boot
```

Env: Windows 7 with i5 and 16 gigs memory and HDD SATA 5400 1TB with Oracle VM 5.0.14x.

Question: How do you setup the Ubuntu VM partitions (assuming that is the issue here) so we have all the space available to docker if it wishes to use them? Ubuntu installation obviously does not refer to this and neither does Docker.

Am not much into Ubuntu and new to Docker, so any help will be great. Thanks.